# What kind of curve, parameterized by arclength $s$, has geodesic curvature $A\cos(ws)+Bw\sin(ws)$ and normal curvature $B\cos(ws)-Aw\sin(ws)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

I don’t know the surface on which a curve lies. Suppose the surface is smooth and allows for Darboux’s rotation minimizing frame to be well defined. All I know is this:

For some constants $A, B, w$, a curve, parametrized by arc length $s$, on the unknown surface has the following expressions for geodesic and normal curvatures, and geodesic torsion respectively:

$$ \kappa_g = A \cos(ws) + B w\sin(ws), \quad \kappa_n = B \cos (ws) - Aw \sin(ws), \quad \tau_g =0.$$

Is this a cylindrical curve? If not, what can I characterize it as?

I used Darboux frame equations to find out how the tetrahedron evolves:
$${\bf T}’ =\kappa_g {\bf t} +{\bf n}\kappa_n, \quad {\bf t}’ = -\kappa_g {\bf T}, \quad {\bf n}’ = -\kappa_n{\bf T}$$
along with $\gamma’ =T$ where $\gamma(s)$ is the parametrized curve on the surface. Here, derivative of a quantity with respect to $s$ has a superscript $’$.

I numerically integrated the above set of differential equations for some initial conditions and it seemed as if they were cylindrical curves (like cylindrical helices)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Swaroop: Is $s$ arc-length?

Comment: @Narasimham: yes!

Comment: Geodesic and normal curvature are meaningless without a surface on which the curve lies. How do you expect this to be a well-posed question?

Comment: @Swaroop Darbha: On variable $\kappa_n$  surfaces  many $(\kappa_g- s)$  intrinsic equation integrand curves can be  bent and embedded. Not a unique surface/curve.